# Eclipse AndroidRunTime Error. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, runtime-error, android-runtime

I got an AndroidRunTime Error and don't know what I am doing wrong. The Problem appears if I try to go from one activity to a next. If I start the app everything is ok and I can Change from one activity to the next. But after a time it stops working, although the activites are very similar...

LogCat:

```
        Tag: AndroidRunTime

        FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.moja.wbf/com.moja.wbf.GL}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.moja.wbf.GL.onCreate(GL.java:13)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 23 more
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
    09-05 08:15:49.681: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 26 more
```

XML-Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/eins" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:onClick="Zwei"
        android:text="WEITER" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Rad" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?` You are not posting your **full** LogCat. Post your Manifest, also.

Comment: Post complete error stack trace

Comment: Ok, I changed it. The manifest is ok...

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` are you using a large `Bitmap` in your second `Activity`?

Comment: I use jpg or png and they are not more as 180KB. Ist that too much?

Comment: 640 x 480 in hdpi. My test device is Android Emulator: Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `OutOfMemoryError` happens because of your images. The actual image `size` doesn't matter but the dimensions do.

Example: a `JPEG`, when uncompressed, allocates 24 bits per pixel (8 bits for red, green and blue accordingly). So if we take one 1920x1080 image as example: 1920px*1080px*24bit / 1024(KB) / 1024(MB) / 8(bits in byte) = appox. 6 MByte of memory are allocated per image. Using many of them can cause a heap overflow.

Beside of that, Android's `BitmapFactory` tends to fail sometimes when decoding large images ("large" in terms of pixels), thus it's recommended to check your `Bitmap`'s dimensions and downscale it appropriately.  There are a lot of examples around, take a look at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) covering this topic.